# Cell shading without removing lines

Tags: tables, color, longtable

I was wondering if there is any way to shade some cells in table without removing lines. I starged with this command

```
\cellcolor[gray]{0.9}
```

however upper line of the cell disapeard. Is there any better way to color some cells ??
PS 
I use longtable

Here is the code

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{mwrep}
\usepackage[MeX]{polski}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=3.0cm,right=3cm,top=3.0cm,bottom=3.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[centerlast]{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[section] {placeins}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\linespread{1.3}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{!{\vrule width 2pt}c!{\vrule width 2pt}c!{\vrule width 2pt}c|c|c!{\vrule width 2pt}c|c|c!{\vrule width 2pt}c!{\vrule width 2pt}c!{\vrule width 2pt}}
\caption{Zależność wydajności algorytmu od jego parametrów.}
\label{tab:parameters}
\\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Parametr} & \multirow{2}{*}{Wartość} & \multicolumn{3}{|c!{\vrule width 2pt}}{\textbf{Czas[s]}}  & \multicolumn{3}{|c!{\vrule width 2pt}}{$\rho_{a}$} \\ \cline{3-10}
& & Zestaw 1 & Zestaw 2  & Zestaw 3  & Zestaw 1  & Zestaw 2  & Zestaw 3 \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{$\rho_{select}$} &  0.5 &   58.0    &   266.4   &   131.4   &   0.98    &   0.8 &   0.95        \\ \cline{2-10}
    & 0.6   &   55.0    &   270.1   &   145.6   &   0.95    &   0.85    &   0.85        \\ \cline{2-10}
    & \cellcolor[gray]{0.9} 0.7 &   55.3    &   256.6   &   143.1   &   0.99    &   0.75    &   0.90        \\ \cline{2-10}
    & 0.8   &   72.0    &   347.2   &   156.9   &   1.00    &   0.87    &   0.97        \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Your problem here is noted as a 'feature' of `\cline{...}` when using it in conjunction with `\cellcolor{...}`. The [`colortbl` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/colortbl) [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/colortbl/colortbl.pdf) mentions the following:

> **10 Less fun with `\cline`**
>
> Lines produced by `\cline` are coloured if you use `\arrayrulecolor` but
>   you may not notice as they are covered up by any colour pannels in the
>   following row. This is a 'feature' of `\cline`. If using this package
>   you would probably better using the `-` rule type in a `\hhline` argument, 
>   rather than `\cline`.

Therefore, my suggestion uses the [`hhline` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/hhline) from the same author (David Carlisle). See the [package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/hhline.pdf) for more details on how to specify the `\hhline` rules:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{mwrep}
...
\usepackage{hhline}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hhline
\begin{longtable}{!{\vrule width 2pt}c!{\vrule width 2pt}c!{\vrule width 2pt}c|c|c!{\vrule width 2pt}c|c|c!{\vrule width 2pt}c!{\vrule width 2pt}c!{\vrule width 2pt}}
\caption{Zaleznosc wydajnosci algorytmu od jego parametrów.}
\label{tab:parameters}
\\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Parametr} & \multirow{2}{*}{Wartosc} & \multicolumn{3}{|c!{\vrule width 2pt}}{\textbf{Czas[s]}}  & \multicolumn{3}{|c!{\vrule width 2pt}}{$\rho_{a}$} \\ \cline{3-10}
& & Zestaw 1 & Zestaw 2  & Zestaw 3  & Zestaw 1  & Zestaw 2  & Zestaw 3 \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{$\rho_{select}$} &  0.5 &   58.0    &   266.4   &   131.4   &   0.98    &   0.8 &   0.95        \\ \cline{2-10}
    & 0.6   &   55.0    &   270.1   &   145.6   &   0.95    &   0.85    &   0.85        \\ \hhline{|~|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|}% New line specification
    & \cellcolor[gray]{0.9} 0.7 &   55.3    &   256.6   &   143.1   &   0.99    &   0.75    &   0.90        \\ \cline{2-10}
    & 0.8   &   72.0    &   347.2   &   156.9   &   1.00    &   0.87    &   0.97        \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image: Longtable with \hhline horizontal lines]

However, the problem is not entire gone as you can see when you zoom in to the spread of the empty horizontal line (via the `~` `\hhline` specifier) across column 1:

[image: \hhline artefact in longtable]

I think this stems from your use of `\vrule width 2pt` as your column rules/widths. And, as such, may be hard to circumvent. This minute problem will most certainly not show up in print, and may therefore be not a problem. Moreover, similar misalignment have gone unnoticed across some of the vertical lines in your columns:

[image: Longtable with vertical misaligned lines]

These are more readily fixed using

```
\multicolumn{3}{c!{\vrule width 2pt}}{\textbf{Czas[s]}} &
\multicolumn{3}{c!{\vrule width 2pt}}{$\rho_{a}$} \
```

instead of

```
\multicolumn{3}{|c!{\vrule width 2pt}}{\textbf{Czas[s]}} &
\multicolumn{3}{|c!{\vrule width 2pt}}{$\rho_{a}$} \
```

Also note the slight misaligned `0.7` with the rest of the columns entries. That's from leaving a space between the cell colour definition and the actual cell entry:

```
\cellcolor[gray]{0.9} 0.7
```

Fix this with:

```
\cellcolor[gray]{0.9}0.7
```

Comment: Hmm, I checked my document in quite a lot of zoom levels, but all the time the upper lines are missing

Comment: Then post a minimal working example of the `longtable` for others to work with.

Comment: I edited my question and added some code

Comment: See my revised answer that (somewhat) addresses your concern. Perhaps not optimal, but I'm not sure whether this is sufficient. Your problem deals with a 'feature' of the `\cline` command.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of `nicematrix` provides a solution to that problem.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions
  {
    custom-line = 
     {
       letter = I ,
       tikz = { line width = 2 pt } 
     }
  }

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\begin{NiceTabular}{Iwc{17mm}Iwc{13mm}Ic|c|cIc|c|cI}[hlines,color-inside]
  \Block{2-1}{Parametr} & \Block{2-1}{Wartość} & \Block{1-3}{\textbf{Czas[s]}} &&& \Block{1-3}{$\rho_{a}$} &&\\ 
  & & Zestaw 1 & Zestaw 2  & Zestaw 3  & Zestaw 1  & Zestaw 2  & Zestaw 3 \\ 
  \Block{4-1}{$\rho_{\text{select}}$} &  0.5 &   58.0    &   266.4   &   131.4   &   0.98    &   0.8 &   0.95 \\ 
      & 0.6 &   55.0    &   270.1   &   145.6   &   0.95    &   0.85    &   0.85 \\ 
      & \cellcolor{gray!15}
        0.7 &   55.3    &   256.6   &   143.1   &   0.99    &   0.75    &   0.90 \\ 
      & 0.8 &   72.0    &   347.2   &   156.9   &   1.00    &   0.87    &   0.97 \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations.

[image: Output of the first code]

However, the output is not perfect in the corners (it's not usual to have a frame with rules of different widths...).

[image: Zoom on a corner of the tabular]

It's possible to adjust the first and the last horizontal rules to have a perfect output.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions
  {
    custom-line = 
     {
       letter = I ,
       tikz = { line width = 2 pt } 
     }
  }

\newcommand{\MyHline}{\Hline[tikz={shorten < = -1pt, shorten > = -0.8pt}]}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\begin{NiceTabular}{Iwc{17mm}Iwc{13mm}Ic|c|cIc|c|cI}[color-inside]
\MyHline
  \Block{2-1}{Parametr} & \Block{2-1}{Wartość} & \Block{1-3}{\textbf{Czas[s]}} &&& \Block{1-3}{$\rho_{a}$} &&\\ 
\Hline
  & & Zestaw 1 & Zestaw 2  & Zestaw 3  & Zestaw 1  & Zestaw 2  & Zestaw 3 \\ 
\Hline
  \Block{4-1}{$\rho_{\text{select}}$} &  0.5 &   58.0    &   266.4   &   131.4   &   0.98    &   0.8 &   0.95 \\ 
\Hline
      & 0.6 &   55.0    &   270.1   &   145.6   &   0.95    &   0.85    &   0.85 \\ 
\Hline
      & \cellcolor{gray!15}
        0.7 &   55.3    &   256.6   &   143.1   &   0.99    &   0.75    &   0.90 \\ 
\Hline
      & 0.8 &   72.0    &   347.2   &   156.9   &   1.00    &   0.87    &   0.97 \\
\MyHline
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Part of the output of the second code]