# \hhline overlay \vline in coloured tabular

Tags: tables, formatting, color, cellcolor, hhline

I'm creating a table containing HTML colour and merged cells. However, some `\cline`/`\hline` have not the default `\arrayrulewidth`.
I tried to use `\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}` before `\cline`/`\hline` but failed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|l|}
\hline
                            & 1                                              & 2           & 3       & 4                                     \\\hline  
\cellcolor[HTML]{FFE2CC} A  & B                                              & C           & D       & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFF2CC}E} \\\hline  
\cellcolor[HTML]{CDDAED}    & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DAE8FC}F} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DAE8FC}}    \\\cline{2-4}  
\cellcolor[HTML]{CDDAED}    & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DAE8FC}G} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DAE8FC}}    \\\cline{2-4}  
\cellcolor[HTML]{CDDAED}    & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DAE8FC}H} & \cellcolor[HTML]{DAE8FC}   \\\cline{2-4}  
\cellcolor[HTML]{CDDAED}    & \cellcolor[HTML]{DAE8FC}I                      & \cellcolor[HTML]{DAE8FC}  &\cellcolor[HTML]{DAE8FC}J &   \cellcolor[HTML]{DAE8FC}    \\\cline{2-2} \cline{4-4} 
\cellcolor[HTML]{CDDAED}    & \cellcolor[HTML]{DAE8FC}                       & \cellcolor[HTML]{DAE8FC}  &\cellcolor[HTML]{DAE8FC}K &   \cellcolor[HTML]{DAE8FC}     \\\cline{4-4}  
\multirow{-6}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{CDDAED}J} & \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DAE8FC}}    & \multirow{-3}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DAE8FC}}    &\cellcolor[HTML]{DAE8FC}L        &   \cellcolor[HTML]{DAE8FC}          \\\cline{1-4}  
\cellcolor[HTML]{D4B1E5}                               & \cellcolor[HTML]{E1D5E7}N                                    & \cellcolor[HTML]{E1D5E7}O                        &\cellcolor[HTML]{E1D5E7}N         &  \cellcolor[HTML]{E1D5E7}  \\\cline{2-4}  
\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{D4B1E5}E}    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E1D5E7}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E1D5E7}} &\cellcolor[HTML]{E1D5E7}Z       &  \cellcolor[HTML]{E1D5E7}     \\\cline{1-5}
\end{tabular}}
\caption{With color}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Table with color]

I followed [Werner's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25065/125774) which use `\hhline`, but the white rule is more emphasized in coloured cells.

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|l|}
\hline
                            & 1                                              & 2           & 3       & 4                                     \\\hline  
\cellcolor[HTML]{FFE2CC} A  & B                                              & C           & D       & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFF2CC}E} \\\hline  
\cellcolor[HTML]{CDDAED}    & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DAE8FC}F} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DAE8FC}}    \\\hhline{|~|-|-|-|~|}  
\cellcolor[HTML]{CDDAED}    & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DAE8FC}G} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DAE8FC}}    \\\hhline{|~|-|-|-|~|}  
\cellcolor[HTML]{CDDAED}    & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DAE8FC}H} & \cellcolor[HTML]{DAE8FC}   \\\hhline{|~|-|-|-|~|}  
\cellcolor[HTML]{CDDAED}    & \cellcolor[HTML]{DAE8FC}I                      & \cellcolor[HTML]{DAE8FC}  &\cellcolor[HTML]{DAE8FC}J &   \cellcolor[HTML]{DAE8FC}    \\\hhline{|~|-|~|-|~|}
\cellcolor[HTML]{CDDAED}    & \cellcolor[HTML]{DAE8FC}                       & \cellcolor[HTML]{DAE8FC}  &\cellcolor[HTML]{DAE8FC}K &   \cellcolor[HTML]{DAE8FC}     \\\hhline{|~|~|~|-|~|}
\multirow{-6}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{CDDAED}J} & \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DAE8FC}}    & \multirow{-3}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DAE8FC}}    &\cellcolor[HTML]{DAE8FC}L        &   \cellcolor[HTML]{DAE8FC}          \\\hhline{|-|-|-|-|~|}
\cellcolor[HTML]{D4B1E5}                               & \cellcolor[HTML]{E1D5E7}N                                    & \cellcolor[HTML]{E1D5E7}O                        &\cellcolor[HTML]{E1D5E7}N         &  \cellcolor[HTML]{E1D5E7}  \\\hhline{|~|-|-|-|~|}  
\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{D4B1E5}E}    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E1D5E7}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E1D5E7}} &\cellcolor[HTML]{E1D5E7}Z       &  \cellcolor[HTML]{E1D5E7}     \\\hline
\end{tabular}}
\caption{Using \texttt{hhline}}
\end{table}
```

[image: Using \hhline]

I then found [Zarko's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/403395/125774) which consist of colour `\hhline`

```
\definecolor{M1}{HTML}{CDDAED}
\definecolor{M2}{HTML}{DAE8FC}

\begin{table}
\centering
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{!{\color{black}\vrule}c!{\color{black}\vrule}c!{\color{black}\vrule}c!{\color{black}\vrule}c!{\color{black}\vrule}l!{\color{black}\vrule}}
\hline
                                            & 1                                              & 2                                                    & 3                              & 4                                     \\\hline  
\cellcolor[HTML]{FFE2CC} A                  & B                                              & C                                                    & D                              & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFF2CC}E} \\\hline  
\cellcolor[HTML]{CDDAED}                    & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DAE8FC}F} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DAE8FC}}                                                                   \\\hhline{|>{\arrayrulecolor{M1}}-|>{\arrayrulecolor{M2}}-|>{\arrayrulecolor{M2}}-|>{\arrayrulecolor{M2}}-|>{\arrayrulecolor{M2}}-|>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}} 
\cellcolor[HTML]{CDDAED}                    & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DAE8FC}G} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DAE8FC}}                                                                   \\\hhline{|>{\arrayrulecolor{M1}}-|>{\arrayrulecolor{M2}}-|>{\arrayrulecolor{M2}}-|>{\arrayrulecolor{M2}}-|>{\arrayrulecolor{M2}}-|>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}}
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
```

The code above gives me this :

[image: hhline coloured]

but it's quite complicated and the intersections of `\hhline` and `\vline` are not in black. This issue can be solved if we could draw `vline` after `\hhline`. Is there a more elegant way to deal with such problem? Changing rule's colour is annoying.

Comment: Welcome to TexSE!!  Great 1st question.

Comment: In my experience the only way to get good lines in colored tables is to redraw them at the end of the table with e.g. tikz: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/409650/line-problem-when-use-color-table/409657#409657

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am a fan of packages that include others with improvements, in this case through the [tabu package](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabu), you can vary the thickness and style of the horizontal lines with a single command `\tabulinestyle{2pt black}` but it will occur that spaces will appear, for that reason you must manually subtract the thickness at the end of new row command `& foo \\[-barpt]`, where `bar` is the thickness of the line and do not forget to declare `\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{2pt}` for the `\cline` command also with the same desired thicknness, for example in the code if I change the `\tabulinestyle{3pt black}` and I do not change the value in `& foo \\[-2pt]` I get this error:

[image]

In the MWE, is defined on 2pt `\tabulinestyle{2pt black}` and all the new row commands are substracted using `& foo \\[-2pt]`and I get this:
[image]

The code is based on easy to read structure:

```
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes, action: nonstopmode}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu,booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% to not write all of these many times...
\definecolor{C1}{HTML}{FFE2CC}
\definecolor{C2}{HTML}{FFF2CC}
\definecolor{C3}{HTML}{DAE8FC}
\definecolor{C4}{HTML}{D4B1E5}
\definecolor{C5}{HTML}{E1D5E7}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{2pt} % To declare the \cline width
\arrayrulecolor{blue} % If you need to change the color of \cline
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \tabulinesep = 2mm
        \tabulinestyle{2pt blue}
        \begin{tabu}to 6cm {|X[2c]|X[c]|X[c]|X[c]|X[2c]|}
            \tabucline -
            %Row 1
            &1
            &2
            &3
            &4\\ \tabucline -  
            %Row 2
            \cellcolor{C1}A
            &B
            &C
            &D
            &\cellcolor{C2}E \\ \tabucline - 
            %Row 3
            \cellcolor{black!20!C3}    
            & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\cellcolor{C3}F} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor{C3}}    \\[-2pt] \tabucline{2-4} 
            %Row 4
            \cellcolor{black!20!C3}
            &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{\cellcolor{C3}G}
            & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor{C3} } \\[-2pt] \tabucline{2-4}  
            %Row 5
            \cellcolor{black!20!C3}
            & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\cellcolor{C3}H}
            & \cellcolor{C3}\\[-2pt] \tabucline{2-4}  
            %Row 6
            \cellcolor{black!20!C3}
            &\cellcolor{C3}I
            &\cellcolor{C3}
            &\cellcolor{C3}J
            &\cellcolor{C3}\\[-2pt] \cline{2-2}\tabucline{4-4} %<-that is something unespected good result!
            %Row 7
            \cellcolor{black!20!C3}
            &\cellcolor{C3}
            &\cellcolor{C3}
            &\cellcolor{C3}K
            &\cellcolor{C3} \\[-2pt] \tabucline{4-4}  
            %Row 8
            \multirow{-6}{*}{\cellcolor{black!20!C3}J}
            &\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor{C3}}
            &\multirow{-3}{*}{\cellcolor{C3}}
            &\cellcolor{C3}L
            &\cellcolor{C3}\\[-2pt] \tabucline{1-4}
            %Row 9
            \cellcolor{C4}
            &\cellcolor{C5}N
            &\cellcolor{C5}O
            &\cellcolor{C5}N
            &\cellcolor{C3}\\[-2pt] \tabucline{2-4}  
            %Row 10
            \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor{C4}E}
            &\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor{C5}}
            &\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor{C5}}
            &\cellcolor{C5}Z
            &\cellcolor{C3}\\ \tabucline -
        \end{tabu}
        \caption{Table for testing colors and rules in tabu}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is how to do it with `hhline`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array, multirow, hhline, booktabs}

\definecolor{blue1}{HTML}{CDDAED}
\definecolor{blue2}{HTML}{DAE8FC}
\definecolor{mauve}{HTML}{E1D5E7}
\definecolor{violet}{HTML}{D4B1E5}

\newcommand{\hhlinea}{\hhline{|>{\arrayrulecolor{blue1}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|-|-|-|>{\arrayrulecolor{blue2}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|}}
\newcommand{\hhlineb}{\hhline{|>{\arrayrulecolor{blue1}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|-|>{\arrayrulecolor{blue2}}-%
>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|-|>{\arrayrulecolor{blue2}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|}}
\newcommand{\hhlinec}{\hhline{|>{\arrayrulecolor{blue1}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|%
*{2}{>{\arrayrulecolor{blue2}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|}-|>{\arrayrulecolor{blue2}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|c|*{3}{c|}>{\columncolor{blue2}}l|}
\hline
\rowcolor{white} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\hline
\rowcolor{white} \cellcolor[HTML]{FFE2CC} A & B & C & D & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFF2CC}E} \\
\hline
\rowcolor{blue2}\cellcolor{blue1} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{F} & \\
\hhlinea
\rowcolor{blue2}\cellcolor{blue1} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{G} & \\
\hhlinea
\rowcolor{blue2}\cellcolor{blue1} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{H} & \\
\hhlinea
\rowcolor{blue2}\cellcolor{blue1} & I & & J & \\
\hhlineb
\rowcolor{blue2}\cellcolor{blue1} & & & K & \\
\hhlinec
\rowcolor{blue2}\multirow{-6}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{CDDAED}J} & & & L & \\
\hhline{|-|-|-|-|>{\arrayrulecolor{mauve}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|}
\rowcolor{mauve}\cellcolor{violet} & N & O & N & \\
\hhline{|>{\arrayrulecolor{violet}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|-|-|-|>{\arrayrulecolor{mauve}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|}
\rowcolor{mauve}\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor{violet}E} & & & Z & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}}
\caption{Using \texttt{hhline}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I finally use this solution since I used already `\hhline`. I will vote up when I have privilege. Just note here that [hhline is incompatible with beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/404872/are-beamer-hhline-and-tablexcolor-incompatible)(I moved it later to beamer and it strangely doesn't work).

Comment: I don't use beamer very often, but I'm not surprised: I know it's incompatible with a number of packages, most notably `enumitem` for lists.

Answer (score 5):

The package `nicematrix` provides tools designed to solve that kind of problems.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\definecolor{color1}{HTML}{FFE2CC}
\definecolor{color2}{HTML}{FFF2CC}
\definecolor{color3}{HTML}{CDDAED}
\definecolor{color4}{HTML}{DAE8FC}
\definecolor{color5}{HTML}{E1D5E7}
\definecolor{color6}{HTML}{D4B1E5}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccl}[hvlines,colortbl-like]
 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\cellcolor{color1}A  & B & C & D & \cellcolor{color2}E \\
\Block[fill=color3]{6-1}{J} & \Block[fill=color4]{1-3}{F} & & & \Block[fill=color4]{6-1}{} \\
 & \Block[fill=color4]{1-3}{G} \\
 & \Block[fill=color4]{1-3}{H} \\
 & \cellcolor{color4}I & \Block[fill=color4]{3-1}{}  & \cellcolor{color4}J \\
 & \Block[fill=color4]{2-1}{}  &   & \cellcolor{color4}K \\
 & & & \cellcolor{color4}L \\
\Block[fill=color6]{2-1}{E} & \cellcolor{color5}N & \cellcolor{color5}O &\cellcolor{color5}N &  \Block[fill=color5]{2-1}{}  \\
 & \cellcolor{color5} & \cellcolor{color5} &\cellcolor{color5}Z &  \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption{With color}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

- In `{NiceTabular}` (which is similar to `{tabular}` of `array`), you have a command `\Block` to merge cells horizontally and vertically. You can specify the color of the block with the key `color`.
- With the key `hvlines`, all the rules are drawn, excepted in the blocks (created by `\Block`).
- You have a good result in all the PDF viewers (you don't have rules which seem to vanish at some levels of zoom; you don't have the thin white lines you see for instance in the viewers using MuPDF such as SumatraPDF when the tabular is constructed with `colortbl`).
- However, you need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]

It's also possible to specify the colors of the cells, rows and columns before the body of the tabular with the keyword `\CodeBefore` (and `Body`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccl}[hvlines]
\CodeBefore
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFE2CC}{2-1}
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFF2CC}{2-5}
  \rectanglecolor[HTML]{CDDAED}{3-1}{8-1}
  \rectanglecolor[HTML]{DAE8FC}{3-2}{8-5}
  \rectanglecolor[HTML]{E1D5E7}{9-2}{10-5}
  \rectanglecolor[HTML]{D4B1E5}{9-1}{10-1} 
\Body
    & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
  A & B & C & D & E \\
  \Block{6-1}{J} & \Block{1-3}{F} & & & \Block{6-1}{} \\
    & \Block{1-3}{G} \\
    & \Block{1-3}{H} \\
    & I & \Block{3-1}{}  & J \\
    & \Block{2-1}{}  &   & K \\
    & & & L \\
   \Block{2-1}{E} & N & O &N &  \Block{2-1}{}  \\
    &  &  &Z &  \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption{With color}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The output is the same.

Comment: Your package becomes more and more beautiful and interesting.

Comment: It's good to see a new answer even though it's been 2 years! I haven't tried it, but it looks very concise.

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, I find that ConTeXt's table mechanisms are MUCH cleaner for creating such tables. For example, here is how to create this table using the [extreme tables](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/xtables-mkiv.pdf) mechanism:

```
\definecolor[C1][h=ffe2cc]
\definecolor[C2][h=fff2cc]
\definecolor[C3][h=cddaed]
\definecolor[C4][h=dae8fc]
\definecolor[C5][h=d4b1e5]
\definecolor[C6][h=e1d5e7]

\setupxtable[mytable]
            [
              option=stretch,
              background=color,
              align={middle,lohi},
              rulethickness=2pt,
              textwidth=6cm,
            ]

\starttext
\startxtable[mytable]
  \startxrow  
    \startxcell   \stopxcell
    \startxcell 1 \stopxcell
    \startxcell 2 \stopxcell
    \startxcell 3 \stopxcell
    \startxcell 4 \stopxcell
  \stopxrow
  \startxrow  
    \startxcell[backgroundcolor=C1] A \stopxcell
    \startxcell B \stopxcell
    \startxcell C \stopxcell
    \startxcell D \stopxcell
    \startxcell[backgroundcolor=C2] E \stopxcell
  \stopxrow
  \startxrow  
    \startxcell[backgroundcolor=C3,ny=6] J \stopxcell
    \startxcell[backgroundcolor=C4,nx=3] F \stopxcell
    \startxcell[backgroundcolor=C4,ny=8]   \stopxcell
  \stopxrow
  \startxrowgroup[backgroundcolor=C4]
    \startxrow \startxcell[nx=3] G \stopxcell \stopxrow
    \startxrow \startxcell[nx=3] H \stopxcell \stopxrow
    \startxrow 
      \startxcell I \stopxcell
      \startxcell[ny=3] \stopxcell
      \startxcell J \stopxcell
    \stopxrow
    \startxrow
      \startxcell[ny=2] \stopxcell
      \startxcell K \stopxcell
    \stopxrow
    \startxrow \startxcell L \stopxcell \stopxrow
  \stopxrowgroup
  \startxrowgroup[backgroundcolor=C6]
  \startxrow
    \startxcell[backgroundcolor=C5, ny=2] E \stopxcell
    \startxcell N \stopxcell
    \startxcell O \stopxcell
    \startxcell N \stopxcell
  \stopxrow
  \startxrow
    \startxcell   \stopxcell
    \startxcell   \stopxcell
    \startxcell Z \stopxcell
  \stopxrow
  \stopxrowgroup
\stopxtable
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: It looks powerful, but you could exemplify it in a minimum working example (MWE)...

Comment: This is a working example! But in ConTeXt rather than LaTeX.